# Django Sessions, handling of datetime types

Tags: django, session

I'm using sessions in a current django project and recently got a `'Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable'` error - due to the `move_in_date` field below.

When saving a modelform of the below model to the session via:

```
if form.is_valid():
        request.session.update(form.cleaned_data)
```

my model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    house_name_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="house name or number")
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    town_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    same_address = models.BooleanField() 
    move_in_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I've tried to solve the issue by using `DjangoJSONEncoder` as suggested by the docs, which can handle datetimes via the settings with `SESSION_SERIALIZER=DjangoJSONEncoder` (should this be a serializer rather than an encoder?), but trying that or `SESSION_SERIALIZER=PickleSerializer` both give an Attribute error - ... has no attribute 'rsplit'

Additionally I was using django wizard before which stores intermediate data (such as the field causing the date issue above) in the session.   I've now switched that part of the app to use seperate views for flexibility (as signup wasn't just a linear path), django wizard doesn't have this issue,  how does it get round this?

Updated with stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 142, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 58, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 83, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 69, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 98, in encode
    serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 93, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable
```

Stack trace for trying DjangoJSONEncoder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 20, in process_request
    request.session = self.SessionStore(session_key)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 18, in __init__
    super(SessionStore, self).__init__(session_key)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.serializer = import_string(settings.SESSION_SERIALIZER)
  File "/Users/Barclay/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: type object 'DjangoJSONEncoder' has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

Comment: include the full error traceback of the error. What serializer is causing this error? can you post that also?

Comment: Thanks updated with stacktrace, think it uses the default `JSONSerializer` which doesn't support datetime objects

Comment: default jsonserializer won't work. You have to create your own serializer for this.

Comment: Thanks the docs mentioned that DjangoJSONEncoder can be used by that and trying PickleSerializer both cause an attribute error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things of confusion are hitting you:

1. When setting the serializer, do not provide a class reference, but a dotted part. This is seen in the error:

   > module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
2. DjangoJSONEncoder isn't the right fix for a serializer. It is referenced in the documentation as a way to serialize models **before** putting them into the session.
3. If you want to make a smart serializer then you still need to create a Serializer, which should support a `dumps` and `loads` interface, that leverage a [JsonEncoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) and [JsonDecoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) respectively.
4. The Pickle serializer will work just fine, but as said you need to provide the [dotted path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#session-serializer).

If you want to use JSON as serializer, then this might be a good start:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.core.signing import JSONSerializer as BaseJSONSerializer


class SmartJSONSerializer(BaseJSONSerializer):
    def dumps(self, obj):
        return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder).encode('latin-1')
```

Comment: thanks is there a standard decoder that is used with json.loads that can support datetimes as well?

Comment: No, but that's because JSON doesn't have a datetime type. See [here](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/json-datetime#the-problem) for more info and a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect